# By Using Gmail API in android, I want gmail data by filtering between two dates of particular email address

Tags: android, gmail, gmail-api

I am using Gmail API and I want data between two dates.

Here is my code for query which currently I am using.

```
listMessagesMatchingQuery(mService, user, "abc@gmail.com");
```

Tell me how to pass two dates and email address to get the proper response

And I am getting response like

```
  {
  "id" : "1622745d8ee96a59",
  "threadId" : "1622745d8ee96a59"
  }
```

but without date.

Answer (score 0):

You can give seconds since the epoch to `after` and `before` in your query to get messages between two dates.

If you would like messages from `abc@gmail.com` sent between `Wed, 04 Apr 2018 00:00:00 GMT` and `Thu, 05 Apr 2018 00:00:00 GMT` you would write:

```
listMessagesMatchingQuery(mService, user, "from:abc@gmail.com after:1522800000 before:1522886400");
```